# Interrupt INT0 on PIC32MX110F016 not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts, microchip, gpio-external-interrupt

I am trying to put the INT0 working in a [PIC32MX110F016](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001168H.pdf) but it seems it never goes there.
The INTO pin is Electrically powered with a pull-up resistor and when I press a tactile button it goes from logic 1 to 0 but it seems the interrupt never happens in my code.

```
void interruptInit(){
INTCONbits.INT0EP = 0;      // edge polarity ( 1 rising, 0 falling edge )
INTCONCLR = 0x00000001; // clear the bit for falling edge trigger
IPC0bits.INT0IP = 4;       // interrupt priority
IPC0bits.INT0IS = 1;       // interrupt sub priority = 1   
IFS0SET = 0x00000002; 
IFS0CLR = 0x00000003; 
IEC0SET = 0x00000003;       // enable INT0 interrupt
}


void __ISR(_EXTERNAL_0_VECTOR, ipl4) INT0Interrupt( void) //interrupt
{
if (IFS0bits.INT0IF)  
    IFS0bits.INT0IF = 0;       // clear the INT0 interrupt

} 


int32_t main(void) {
interruptInit();
while (1); }
```

Comment: I think at the very least you need INTCONbits.MVEC = 1. There's a library function which does this (and possibly some other stuff) called something like SysEnableMultiVectorInterrupts().

Comment: yes I included INTCONbits.MVEC = 1 but it's not working yet. I haven't included libraries at this point because I just installed the IDE a few minutes ago.

Comment: Well actually this is a new pc where I am work with and it seems I am facing another problem in including libraries. Can you help me with that @brhans? thanks.

Comment: How do you know it never happens? All you are doing in the ISR is clearing the interrupt flag. Update the code in your post to reflect any changes you've made so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications including enable the interrupts and the system multi vector for interrupts. In the interruptInit() function I decided to erase all the initial configurations and look at the datasheet in order to clarify and enable only the relevant pins. By know the interrupt (INT0) is working fine.

```
void __ISR( _EXTERNAL_0_VECTOR, ipl2) InterruptHandler_INT0 (void){ 
IFS0bits.INT0IF = 0;
}

void interruptInit(){
INTCONbits.INT0EP = 0;
IPC0bits.INT0IS = 0;
IPC0bits.INT0IP = 1;
IEC0bits.INT0IE = 1;
IFS0bits.INT0IF = 0; 
}

int32_t main(void) {
__asm__("EI"); 
INTConfigureSystem(INT_SYSTEM_CONFIG_MULT_VECTOR); //configure multi vector
INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt(); //enable interrupts
interruptInit()
while (1);
}
```

Comment: It's great you answered your own question, but why don't you describe the changes you made that actually fixed the problem? That way if someone has a similar problem in the future and comes across this answer, they'll understand why you did what you did.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Edited :)